# Self Join to get employee manager name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Hello I have a Employee Table with following columns

```
Emp_id, Emp_Name and Mgr_id.
```

I am trying to create a view which will list

`Emp_id, Emp_name, Mgr_id and Mgr_name` (by cross joining the Employee table). I tried outer join, inner join etc, but I am not able to get it right.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmployeeDetails](
[emp_id] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
[emp_name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,    
[emp_mgr_id] [bigint] NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEmployeeDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[emp_id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Look back in your class notes for "self join"

Comment: Please update your question & provide full detail.

Comment: It seems that we need to guess your requirements. Please provide some more information, otherwise we all waste our time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT e1.emp_Id EmployeeId, e1.emp_name EmployeeName, 
       e1.emp_mgr_id ManagerId, e2.emp_name AS ManagerName
FROM   tblEmployeeDetails e1
       JOIN tblEmployeeDetails e2
       ON e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id
```

**EDIT**:
Left Join will work if emp_mgr_id is null.

```
CREATE VIEW AS 
SELECT e1.emp_Id EmployeeId, e1.emp_name EmployeeName,  
       e1.emp_mgr_id ManagerId, e2.emp_name AS ManagerName 
FROM   tblEmployeeDetails e1 
       LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeDetails e2 
       ON e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id
```

Comment: This query will not wok when the mgr_id is null.

Comment: Left join is also not working for me. Since I have few cases the mgr_id doesn't exists in the emp_id

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine with the outer join. I had the join statement wrong (instead of e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id I had ON e1.emp_id = e2.emp_mgr_id)

Answer (score 8):

```
   SELECT b.Emp_id, b.Emp_name,e.emp_id as managerID, e.emp_name as managerName
    FROM Employee b
    JOIN Employee e ON b.Emp_ID = e.emp_mgr_id
```

Try this, it's a JOIN on itself to get the manager :)

Comment: This query will not wok when the mgr_id is null.

Comment: Then you just do a left join instead :)

Comment: Left join is also not working for me. Since I have few cases the mgr_id doesn't exists in the emp_id

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE VIEW EmployeeWithManager AS 
SELECT e.[emp id], e.[emp name], m.[emp id], m.[emp name] 
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN Employee m ON e.[emp mgr id] = m.[emp id]
```

This definition uses a left outer join which means that even employees whose manager ID is NULL, or whose manager has been deleted (if your application allows that) will be listed, with their manager's attributes returned as NULL.

If you used an inner join instead, only people who have managers would be listed.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT e1.empno EmployeeId, e1.ename EmployeeName, 
       e1.mgr ManagerId, e2.ename AS ManagerName
FROM   emp e1, emp e2
       where e1.mgr = e2.empno
```

Answer (score 3):

As Jesse said, use self join:

```
SELECT 
  e.emp_id
  , e.emp_name
  , e.emp_mgr_id
  , m.emp_name AS mgr_name 
FROM [dbo].[tblEmployeeDetails] e 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblEmployeeDetails] m ON e.emp_mgr_id = m.emp_id
```

Comment: This query will not wok when the mgr_id is null.

Comment: Left join is also not working for me. Since I have few cases the mgr_id doesn't exists in the emp_id

Comment: either left outer or right outer join should work, if not - then we're missing some setup

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine with the outer join. I had the join statement wrong (instead of e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id I had ON e1.emp_id = e2.emp_mgr_id)

Answer (score 3):

```
    select E1.emp_id [Emp_id],E1.emp_name [Emp_name],
E2.emp_mgr_id [Mgr_id],E2.emp_name [Mgr_name] 
from [tblEmployeeDetails] E1 left outer join
    [tblEmployeeDetails] E2
    on E1.emp_mgr_id=E2.emp_id
```

Comment: yeah I tried this, but I have few cases that the mgr_id doesn't exists in emp_id and it is failing

Comment: if the manager id doesnt exist, it will give null as the manager_id. What do you expect to come instead of that? Please give some examples

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine with the outer join. I had the join statement wrong (instead of e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id I had ON e1.emp_id = e2.emp_mgr_id)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```
SELECT Employee.emp_id, Employee.emp_name,Manager.emp_id as Mgr_Id, Manager.emp_name as Mgr_Name 
FROM tblEmployeeDetails Employee 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeDetails Manager ON Employee.emp_mgr_id = Manager.emp_id
```

Comment: yeah I tried this, but I have few cases that the mgr_id doesn't exists in emp_id and it is failing

Comment: It should work even though mgrId is null or does not exists. If mgrId is not correct / null. It will give null values for Mgr_Id and Mgr_Name.

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine with the outer join. I had the join statement wrong (instead of Employee.emp_mgr_id = Manager.emp_id I had Employee.emp_id = Manager.emp_mgr_id)

Answer (score 2):

try this ..you should do `LEFT JOIN` to igore null values in the table

```
SELECT a.emp_Id EmployeeId, a.emp_name EmployeeName,  
       a.emp_mgr_id ManagerId, b.emp_name AS ManagerName 
FROM   tblEmployeeDetails a 
       LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeDetails b
       ON b.emp_mgr_id = b.emp_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TableName :Manager

EmpId   EmpName     ManagerId
1       Monib       4

2       zahir       1

3       Sarfudding  NULL

4       Aslam       3


select e.EmpId as EmployeeId,e.EmpName as EmployeeName,e.ManagerId as ManagerId,e1.EmpName as Managername from Manager e
  join manager e1 on e.ManagerId=e1.empId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table abc(emp_ID int, manager varchar(20) , manager_id int)

emp_ID  manager manager_id
1       abc     NULL
2       def     1
3       ghi     2
4       klm     3
5       def1    1
6       ghi1    2
7       klm1    3

select a.emp_ID , a.manager emp_name,b.manager manager_name
from abc a
left join abc b
on a.manager_id = b.emp_ID

Result:
emp_ID  emp_name  manager_name
1       abc       NULL
2       def       abc
3       ghi       def
4       klm       ghi
5       def1      abc
6       ghi1      def
7       klm1      ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create view as 
(select 
e1.empno as PersonID,
e1.ename as PersonName,
e2.empno MANAGER_ID,
e2.ename MANAGER_NAME 
from 
employees e1 , employees e2 
where 
e2.empno=e1.mgr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select E1.EmpId,E1.Name,E2.Name as Manager from Employee E1 left join Employee E2 on  E1.ManagerID = E2.EmpId
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you may want to get managers and their reports count with -

```
SELECT e2.ename ,count(e1.ename)  FROM employee_s e1 LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_s e2 
ON e1.manager_id = e2.eid
group by e2.ename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.emp_id, e1.emp_name, e1.mgr_id, e2.emp_name as manager_name

FROM employee e1

JOIN employee e2

ON e1.mgr_id = e2.emp_id

ORDER BY e1.emp_id
```

*Here is the link to SQL Fiddle with a working example.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/392b5/9

Comment: why we take mgr_id  from  e1, not from  e2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct( e1.id), e1.emp_name from employee as e1 
inner join employee as e2 on e1.id = e2.manager_id;
```