# How to retrieve names within a column if values in another column corresponds to the primary key of desired name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in t-sql which looks like this

```
personid | firstname | lastname | managerid
1        | Tom       | Bricks   | null
2        | Joe       | Liam     | 1
3        | Mary      | Hattan   | 2
```

I am trying to query out a table like this:

```
Name | ManagerName
Tom  | No manager
Joe  | Tom
Mary | Joe
```

I can't seem to figure out way how to query the second column out my query as it stands is like this :

```
SELECT 'firstname' + ' ' + 'lastname' AS 'Name
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Are you really working with all of MySQL, SQL Server and postgresql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self Join to get employee manager name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427300/self-join-to-get-employee-manager-name)

Comment: use self join in SQL

Comment: Or a correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Self Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx) to get data using two column link on the same table.

Try this

```
   SELECT t1.firstname as Name, ISNULL(t2.firstname,'No manager') as ManagerName
   FROM   tblName t1 
       LEFT JOIN tblName t2 
       ON t1.managerid = t2.personid
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebb6/3)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help - the problem is that the manager id corresponds to the personid in table 1. There is no second table, I am quiet confused about this.

Comment: Yes, Right, there is no second table, thats why if you see the query, I join One table two time "tblName", just using two instance t1, and t2. This is called self join

Comment: You can also check the DEMO link, which shows the how this query works

Comment: Wow....thank you very much I look at it...this is very new technique...many appreciation for the tips....so this function t1. , t2. allows duplication of a specific table in a way..?

Comment: Yes you have to have aliases so that it distinguishes between the two instnces of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      personid INT ,
      firstname NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      lastname NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      managerid INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'Tom', 'Bricks', NULL ),
        ( 2, 'Joe', 'Liam', 1 ),
        ( 3, 'Mary', 'Hattan', 2 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   personid ,
                        firstname ,
                        lastname ,
                        managerid
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    ManagerID IS NULL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.personid ,
                        t.firstname ,
                        t.lastname ,
                        t.managerid
               FROM     @t t
                        INNER JOIN cte ecte ON ecte.personid = t.ManagerID
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
GO
```

Output:

```
personid    firstname   lastname    managerid
1   Tom Bricks  NULL
2   Joe Liam    1
3   Mary    Hattan  2
```