# Mysql how to return specific query result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column of either intergers or NULL, the integers are referencing the primary key of the same table.
I'm trying to query and get a result of a column that has names with the primary key of the integers and retains the NULL if present.

```
CURRENT TABLE

id name   manager_id
1  mike   5
2  lisa   3
3  tom    NULL
4  andy   3
5  brian  NULL

EXPECTED RESULT

id  name  manager_id
1   Mike  Brian
2   Lisa  Tom
3   Tom   NULL
4   Andy  Tom
5   Brian NULL
```

Comment: I feel like I'm on the brink of understanding the question. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result?

Comment: We need to see some sample data before we can tell you for sure.

Comment: You can follow this link to get your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427300/self-join-to-get-employee-manager-name

Answer (score 1):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself. For example:

```
select e.id, e.name, m.name
from t e
left join t m on m.id = e.manager_id
```

Result:

```
 id  name   name  
 --- ------ ----- 
 1   mike   brian 
 2   lisa   tom   
 3   tom    <null>
 4   andy   tom   
 5   brian  <null>
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac4bfc1d4c594ae11425aeb618d9eaa9).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` of two queries. One returns the `NULL` values, the other uses a self-join to get the names from the referenced rows.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, ..., t2.name
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent
WHERE t1.parent IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, ..., t1.parent
FROM yourTable AS t1
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL
```

Comment: I get we don't have all of the information in the OP, but surely a self-joined `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would be advisable over a union here?

Comment: That's another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT e1.emp_Id EmployeeId, e1.emp_name EmployeeName,
e1.emp_mgr_id ManagerId, e2.emp_name AS ManagerName
FROM   tblEmployeeDetails e1
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeDetails e2
ON e1.emp_mgr_id = e2.emp_id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).